# How to upgrade Mate 1.6 to 1.8 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mate

I installed Mate using the official directions (http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download) but it installed 1.6 instead of 1.8. How can I upgrade in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: The MATE repositories haven't been updated to 1.8 yet.

Comment: So you're saying it will update automatically once the repos are updated?

Comment: How exactly you installed mate?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the [way provided here](http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download)? If so, try to re-enter the following into terminal. Especially the `sudo apt-get update` thing.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install mate-archive-keyring
sudo apt-get update
# this installs base packages
sudo apt-get install mate-core
# this installs more packages
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment
```

Then **if the package for 12.04LTS is available**, it should be updated into 1.8.

Please specify more info on your question (about how did you install the MATE).